# CSS hover picture transform and dont disable

Tags: html, css, menu, transform

I have this code:

```
<style>

.menypic:hover { transform:scale(1.1,1.1)}


.menu ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
ul.menu li {display: block;position: relative;float:left;border:0px solid #000;list-style-type: none;}
.menu li ul {display: none;border:0px;}
.menu ul li a {display: block;background: #fff;padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;text-decoration: none;
       white-space: nowrap;color: #000;border:0px; font-family: "Calibri", Times, serif;font-size: 14px;} 
.menu ul li a:hover {background: #fff;}
.menu li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;border-bottom: solid thin #0066ff;border-left: solid thin #0066ff;border-right: solid thin #0066ff;background: #0066ff}
.menu li:hover li {float: none;}
.menu li:hover a  {background: #ffffff;border:0px solid #000;}
.menu li:hover li a:hover {background: #0066ff;border:0px solid #000;color: #fff;text-decoration: none;}

#drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}

</style>
<ul>
<li class="menu">
    <a href="1-4.aspx"><img src="1-4.png" class="menypic"></a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu"><a href="1-4.aspx">&nbsp;Nyheter&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="2014">&nbsp;20 1-4&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And it works brillantly. When I hover the picture it transform to little bigger, and the new menu comes down. Works perfect. But when I hover the menu, the picture goes back to its old size. Is it possible to hold the transformation as long as I am in the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set style for other child elements of (for e.g) menu element, while you are "on" menu element with your mouse cursor.

For e.g you can add:

```
.menu:hover .menypic { transform:scale(1.1,1.1);}
```

..and all your elements with *.menypic class* in .menu will be scaled while element with *.menu class* is in :hover state.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eukjxuqc/3/

***EDIT/UPDATE:*** After reading comments, I hope this is what you need.
Basically, I think this is what you need (this is not from your code, I created new example just to make things easier to understand):

```
ul.submenu li:hover ul.menu li, ul.menu li:hover {transform:scale(1.1,1.1);}
```

***Also, new fiddle link:*** https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/eukjxuqc/5/

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I have many pictures classed as "menypic". So when I use your code all of my menu-pictures get transformed.

But as it is now, when I hover a picture, then that is the only picture which get transformed. So I dont want it to go back to its original size, before I leave the menu.

Comment: So, let's say you have 10 pictures and you hover picture number 7. Then, picture number 7 will be transformed and you want it to keep that transformation wherever you are on current menu? What will happen with other pictures when you hover another one? For e.g you already :hover picture 7 and now you hover picture 3 (which is also part of menu).. will both pictures be transformed or only picture 3 ? @OlaHansen

Comment: Well, if i hover picture number 7, then number 7 should transform and a menu will fall down under picture 7. If i hover picture 3 after, then number 7 should go back to its original size, and picture 3 should transform as a new menu falls down under picture 3.

Comment: @OlaHansen can you please check my update on answer? If I understood well, this is what you asked for..